# What does Error: Provided address "1.2870172725867908e+48" is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed

Tags: web3js, blockchain, checksum

I have assigned my variables here

```
> var contractAddress = 0xb5A5F22694352C15B00323844aD545ABb2B11028

> var cont = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress)
```

I am getting the error :

> Error: Provided address "1.2870172725867908e+48" is invalid, the
>   capitalization checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address
>   which can't be converted.
>       at Object.inputAddressFormatter (/Users/tycooperaow/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/formatters.js:409:11)
>       at Object.set [as address] (/Users/tycooperaow/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:92:69)
>       at Contract (/Users/tycooperaow/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:217:26)
>       at new Contract (/Users/tycooperaow/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-eth/src/index.js:149:22)

This is the variable I used to assign the abi

```
var abi = [ { constant: false,
    inputs: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    name: 'approve',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: true,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'totalSupply',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: false,
    inputs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    name: 'transferFrom',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: false,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'enableTokenTransfer',
    outputs: [],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: false,
    inputs: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    name: 'unlockAddress',
    outputs: [],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: true,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'walletAddress',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: true,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'tokenTransfer',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: false,
    inputs: [ [Object] ],
    name: 'burnTokens',
    outputs: [],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: true,
    inputs: [ [Object] ],
    name: 'balanceOf',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: true,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'owner',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: false,
    inputs: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    name: 'transfer',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: true,
    inputs: [ [Object] ],
    name: 'lockaddress',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: true,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'creationTime',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: true,
    inputs: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    name: 'allowance',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: false,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'disableTokenTransfer',
    outputs: [],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: true,
    inputs: [ [Object] ],
    name: 'unlockaddress',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: false,
    inputs: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    name: 'lockAddress',
    outputs: [],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { constant: true,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'lock',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    type: 'function' },
  { inputs: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    type: 'constructor' },
  { anonymous: false,
    inputs: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    name: 'TokenBurned',
    type: 'event' },
  { anonymous: false,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'TokenTransfer',
    type: 'event' },
  { anonymous: false,
    inputs: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    name: 'Locked',
    type: 'event' },
  { anonymous: false,
    inputs: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    name: 'Unlocked',
    type: 'event' },
  { anonymous: false,
    inputs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    name: 'Transfer',
    type: 'event' },
  { anonymous: false,
    inputs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    name: 'Approval',
    type: 'event' } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contract address should be a string (use the quotes)

var contractAddress = '0xb5A5F22694352C15B00323844aD545ABb2B11028'

Hope this helps

Comment: In addition to that, the value of `0xb5A5F22694352C15B00323844aD545ABb2B11028` is larger than Javascript's `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. So even if it was allowed to pass a `web3.BigNumber` here, the user would still need to encapsulate this value with quotes (or double-quotes).